# How to test a react component properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, recompose

I'm not an expert about unit testing, and i'm trying to achieve 100% coverage on my dummy todoapp project, its easy for simple components like a TodoList component, but what about the AddTodo component?

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {compose, withState, withProps} from 'recompose'

/**
* Form to create new todos.
*/

const enhance = compose(
  withState('value', 'setValue', ''),
  withProps(({value, setValue, addTodo}) => ({
    handleSubmit: e => (
      e.preventDefault(),
      addTodo(value),
      setValue('')
    ),
    handleChange: e => setValue(e.target.value),
  }))
)

const Component = ({value, handleSubmit, handleChange}) =>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <input type="submit" value="add"/>
  </form>

Component.displayName = 'FormNewTodo'
Component.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default enhance(Component)
```

This is my current AddTodo test:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import FormNewTodo from './index'

test('it should render properly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<FormNewTodo value="something"/>)

  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

That test give produce the following coverage: Stmts 62.5, Branch 100, Funcs 25, Lines 62.5.

The uncovered Lines are: 12, 16, 21.

How should I test them correctly? What i'm missing? There are some resources out there about the topic?

---

I've finally solved my problem, note that the goal was to achieve 100% coverage and nothing else.

This is my solution:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow} from 'enzyme'
import FormNewTodo from './index'

test('<FormNewTodo/>', () => {
  const preventDefault = jest.fn()
  const addTodo = jest.fn()
  const subject = shallow(
    <FormNewTodo
      addTodo={addTodo}
    />
  )

  subject.dive()
    .find('[type="text"]')
    .simulate('change', {target: {value: 'woot'}})

  subject.dive()
    .simulate('submit', {preventDefault})

  expect(preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(addTodo).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: You might want to check out Create React App's user guide, it has a section about testing React components https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#testing-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handleSubmit` and `handleChange` functions are not called, so the coverage report says these lines are not covered.

Because you've already `enzyme`, you can use it to [simulate](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.md) the events which trigger those handlers.

For example:

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('click') // trigger handleChange
wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit') // trigger handleSubmit
```

Comment: Just remember to use mount instead of shallow when triggering/simulating events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with recompose but I assume that your untested code are the `onChange` and `onSubmit` callback function and that `setValue` and `addTodo` are props of your component. To test this you need to pass them as spies, created with `jest.fn()`, in to your component. Then you have to trigger `onChange` and `onSubmit`, and test on the spies that they were called with the correct arguments

```
test('it submits the form', () => {
  //create the spies for your callbacks
  const setValue = jest.fn()
  const addTodo = jest.fn()

  //pass them to your rendered component
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <FormNewTodo 
      value="something" 
      setValue={setValue} 
      addTodo={addTodo}
    />
  )
  //create a spy for your fake event
  const preventDefault = jest.fn()
  //trigger the submit by just calling the prop
  wrapper.trigger.prop('onSubmit')({preventDefault})
  //check that the functions are called with correct parameter
  expect(preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled()
  expect(setValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith('')
  expect(addTodo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('something')

})
```